# aggregate columns in list on per row basis

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example pandas dataframe:

```
top1_item top2_item top3_item
2         3         4
1         3         6
6         3         2
```

I like to append the dataframe  with a column containining a list of the values of the other columns:

```
top1_item top2_item top3_item together
2         3         4         [2,3,4]
1         3         6         [1,3,6]
6         3         2         [6,3,2]
```

I tried  something like

```
df[['top1_item', 'top2_item', 'top3_item']].agg(list, axis=1)
```

But this won't return the desired pandas Series of lists which I could easily append to my dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, assign a list instead. You don't need to use `agg` either.

```
df['new'] = df.values.tolist()
df

   top1_item  top2_item  top3_item        new
0          2          3          4  [2, 3, 4]
1          1          3          6  [1, 3, 6]
2          6          3          2  [6, 3, 2]
```

If it's a subset of columns you want to aggregate, that's easy:

```
df['new'] = df['col1', 'col2', ...].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that this should be easy. Didn't realised it could be that straight forward. Is there a solution involving agg, in case that I want to do something more complicated like filtering on entries?

Comment: @dennis-ec Using `agg` + `list`? Unfortunately, no, because lists are special-cased by pandas, and the result is almost certainly coerced into a dataframe. Perhaps consider `agg` + `tuple` as an alternative, the same would then work.

Comment: @COLDSPEED You are right! If I try 
df[['top1_item', 'top2_item', 'top3_item']].agg(list, axis=1)
instead it works. So the return type of the custom agg function was the real problem.

Comment: @dennis-ec Exactly. You cannot assign a dataframe slice to a column.

Answer (score 2):

Ummmm, (PS:I do not why we need apply tuple first then convert to list ..)

```
df['New']=df.apply(tuple,1).apply(list)
df
Out[11]: 
   top1_item  top2_item  top3_item        New
0          2          3          4  [2, 3, 4]
1          1          3          6  [1, 3, 6]
2          6          3          2  [6, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Interesting this works, because after the first apply, the column is of `object` type, so pandas no longer makes any assumptions about the contents -- conversion to list is now possible. Very roundabout though, but still nice to know!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep, make a lot of sense :-)